# split a Spark column of Array[String] into columns of String

Tags: arrays, string, apache-spark, split

If I have a Dataframe containing a column of Array[String]:

```
scala> y.show
+---+----------+
|uid|event_comb|
+---+----------+
|  c|  [xx, zz]|
|  b|  [xx, xx]|
|  b|  [xx, yy]|
|  b|  [xx, zz]|
|  b|  [xx, yy]|
|  b|  [xx, zz]|
|  b|  [yy, zz]|
|  a|  [xx, yy]|
+---+----------+
```

How can I split the column `"event_comb"` into two columns (e.g. `"event1"` and `"event2"`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your column type is list or Map you can use getItem function to get the value

`getItem(Object key)`

> An expression that gets an item at position
>   ordinal out of an array, or gets a value by key key in a MapType.

```
val data = Seq(
    ("c", List("xx", "zz")),
  ("b", List("xx", "xx")),
  ("b", List("xx", "yy")),
  ("b", List("xx", "zz")),
  ("b", List("xx", "yy")),
  ("b", List("xx", "zz")),
  ("b", List("yy", "zz")),
  ("a", List("xx", "yy"))
  ).toDF("uid", "event_comb")

  data.withColumn("event1", $"event_comb".getItem(0))
      .withColumn("event2", $"event_comb".getItem(1))
      .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+------+------+
|uid|event_comb|event1|event2|
+---+----------+------+------+
|c  |[xx, zz]  |xx    |zz    |
|b  |[xx, xx]  |xx    |xx    |
|b  |[xx, yy]  |xx    |yy    |
|b  |[xx, zz]  |xx    |zz    |
|b  |[xx, yy]  |xx    |yy    |
|b  |[xx, zz]  |xx    |zz    |
|b  |[yy, zz]  |yy    |zz    |
|a  |[xx, yy]  |xx    |yy    |
+---+----------+------+------+
```